# How read events from solidity

Tags: solidity

I made a solidity contract but I want to get the event in another contract, is it possible to watch the event in that way?

Comment: I mean to watch an event in another contract

Comment: No. At the end of the function which emits the event, return the event values. Then, in any other function which calls this function, you can get these values.

Answer (score 5):

No, events can be emitted by smart contract under Ethereum, but they are not readable by them. They are write-only.